# Draw line with different styles in matplotlib before and after a certain point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
plt.plot(list1[0: x], '-', c="r", linewidth=3)

plt.plot(list1[x:], '.', c="b", linewidth=3)

plt.plot(list2, '-', c="k", linewidth=2)

plt.savefig("myfig")
plt.clf()
```

What I would like to do is to draw as lines the points in list1 and list2, however, before a point x, I want to draw the points in list 1 in a certain style, and after x in a different style. The problem with my code is that I have all three plots starting at 0, so, the line that should come after x does not start at x but at 0. How do i fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the x coordinates to `plt.plot` as well as the y coordinates. So, assuming they are just the integer indices of the items in `list1` and `list2`, you could do this:

```
x1 = range(len(list1))
x2 = range(len(list2))

plt.plot(x1[0:x], list1[0:x], '-', c="r", linewidth=3)

plt.plot(x1[x:], list1[x:], '.', c="b", linewidth=3)

plt.plot(x2, list2, '-', c="k", linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply